# RHEL 6.x - yum gives "ImportError: No module named cElementTree" errors

Tags: python, yum, rhel6

I'm making a set of changes to a group of 150 servers. All systems were able to successfully download and install a specific set of RPM's via `yum`, except for one. One this particular system, all yum commands outside of "clean" dump the following to the screen:

```
[root@dev1v ~]# yum install sssd
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin
/usr/lib64/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py:612: DeprecationWarning: The xmllib module is obsolete.  Use xml.sax instead.
  import xmllib # lazy subclassing (!)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in <module>
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 285, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 136, in main
    result, resultmsgs = base.doCommands()
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 434, in doCommands
    self._getTs(needTsRemove)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/depsolve.py", line 99, in _getTs
    self._getTsInfo(remove_only)
  .
  .
  .
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/repoMDObject.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.parse(srcfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/repoMDObject.py", line 140, in parse
    parser = iterparse(infile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/misc.py", line 1169, in cElementTree_iterparse
    _cElementTree_import()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/misc.py", line 1164, in _cElementTree_import
    import cElementTree
ImportError: No module named cElementTree
```

I've tried:

- yum clean
- reinstalling bits and pieces manually via RPM... `expat`, part of `python`, etc.
- rebuilding the RPM database

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fix:

Apparently, the Oracle installation on this system injected Oracle's path into LD_LIBRARY_PATH...

```
[root@dev1v etc]# export 
declare -x LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib"
```

Unsetting the variable allowed yum to function properly again.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, in python 2.6, cElementTree lives in /usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/cElementTree.py, which is part of the python package. The fact that you're reaching the `import cElementTree` in the yum code indicates that `xml.etree` seems missing.

Try reinstalling python by manually downloading the rpm and using `rpm -Uvh`.

If that doesn't work, what happens if you `import xml.etree.cElementTree` in a python shell? What does `rpm --verify python` say?

Answer (score 1):

I have also seen someone causing this issue by putting Oracle's `lib/` path in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`

Using:

> echo /opt/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/ > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf

Solved this issue by removing `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I resolved this problem as the following: (OS: CentOS 6.3 with Oracle installed).

1. Edit `/etc/profile` and find `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` line if present.
2. Add `/lib64` before `$ORACLE_HOME/lib`

   ```
   export  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib64:$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client/lib
   ```
3. Log out and re-logon as root.

Answer (score 0):

`declare -x` didnt work.
This worked for me.

```
[root@host ~]# unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

If any variable is defined in /etc/ld.so.conf then remove it and run # ldconfig command to recreate ld cache.

```
[root@host ~]# ldconfig
```

Confirm that the Python library now links to the correct /lib64/libexpat.so.1 library.

```
[root@host ~]# ldd /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/pyexpat.so
```

Answer (score -1):

unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH, 
ldconfig, 
ldd /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/pyexpat.so

As mentioned in https://serverfault.com/a/686667/431469, this worked for me.

Comment: Welcome on the ServerFault! Maybe you could elaborate this more, it is now like a magician answer ("and sacrifice a black hen and you will have rain"). Why? How?